# Trapping a DoubleClick in PowerPoint 2007

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The [`Application.WindowBeforeDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231081.aspx) event for PowerPoint 2007 appears to not work (see [here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29622159/windowbeforedoubleclick-e.aspx) to verify my claims). It works in PowerPoint 2003, but not in 2007 (contrary to the documentation).

I'm looking for anything, that will trap the double click event in PowerPoint, such as:

- C++ code (ideally)
- A macro, VBA, something similar
- Trapping Windows messages for double click events

The last one may be my work around, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it appears to be a bug. You can use the `WindowSelectionChange` event instead.

Comment: Its been a while since I asked this question... thanks for the help. I will look at it.